# Stata: how I add an interaction between two variables?

Tags: stata, interaction

I have multiple regression model question:

I am required to add an interaction between two variables in stata, but every time I try and do so (reg log_p c##lux) I get a message prompted, "c:  factor variables may not contain noninteger values".

Any advice on where to go from here?

Comment: I think I may have figured it out, by using: reg log_p c.c##lux, but now I have to interpret whether the interaction is necessary or not, based off the coefficients. Can anyone give me some advice on how to do so?

Comment: When using interactions you need to distinguish between factor (categorical) variables and continous variables. By default when using #, Stata takes variables as factor variables. Continuous variables are denoted with `c.` prefix, factor variables with `i.` prefix, so an interaction between continuous price and factor variable foreign would be `c.price##i.foreign`.